# Trouble finding data from text file

Tags: java

I've been having trouble extracting the data from a text file and using it. I've got an assignment that requires me to get 10 doubles from the file and find the min, max, and average of the numbers. This is what I've got so far.

```html
import java.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class DataAnalysis
{

   static double i;
   
public static void main(String args[])
{
      double sum =0;
      
      
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner("input.txt");
      double min = inputFile.nextDouble();
      double max = inputFile.nextDouble();
      for(i = inputFile.nextDouble(); i < 10; i++)
      {
         if(i < min)
         {
            min = i;
         }
         else
         {
            if(i > max)
            {
               max = i;
            }
         }
         
      }
     double average = sum/ 10;
   System.out.println("Maximum: " + max);
   System.out.println("Minimum: " + min);
   System.out.println("Average: " + average);
}
}
```

It compiles just fine, but I get a Scanner InputMismatchException

```html
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
 at DataAnalysis.main(DataAnalysis.java:20)
```

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: What does your input.txt file look like?

Comment: I also think that the format of the input.txt is not as expected. So would you mind sharing with us?

Comment: Here is my input.txt file
0.32
0.99
0.44
0.65
0.23
0.11
0.22
0.12
1.11
0.39

Answer (score 0):

It might be locale dependent. Decimal numbers are e.g written as 0,5 in Sweden.

Change your code so that it says e.g.:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
scan.useLocale(Locale.US);
```